# Java 10 WebUpd8?

Tags: package-management, java

Is there Java 10 WebUpd8 package available? Are there plans to make one? I could not find much information any where.

Comment: We cannot give any insights to whether there are plans to make one or not, as we are not WebUpd8.

Answer (score 6):

I used the original Oracle Java packaging from WebUpd8 and created a [new PPA](https://launchpad.net/~linuxuprising/+archive/ubuntu/java) for Oracle Java 10.

Edit: Java 10 is no longer supported and thus, no longer in the PPA. If you must use Oracle Java, use [Oracle JDK 11](https://www.linuxuprising.com/2019/06/new-oracle-java-11-installer-for-ubuntu.html) (also available in a PPA), which has long term support.

Answer (score 3):

No there is not.
You can check what are available versions:

```
apt-cache show oracle-java"*"-installer | grep Version
```

Output:
Version: 7u80+7u60arm-0~webupd8~1
Version: 8u161-1~webupd8~0
Version: 9.0.4-1~webupd8~0
Version: 6u45-0~webupd8~8

[Most recent news from WebUpd8 on Java is about JDK 9 and that is considered stable.](https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/ubuntu/java)